# Why won't my iPhone tell the difference between 960px & 640px style sheets

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have these 2 rules:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:960px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobileStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:640px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobilePortraitStyles.css">
```

They work on my browser (when I adjust the browser width) but when I check them on my iPhone, either portrait or landscape, it loads both style sheets.

Why on landscape view it loads the 640px style sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the web view size of iPhone safari browser is either 320x480px or 480x320px in landscape for both display type. so the web developer don't need to resize his css for Non-Retina and Retina Displays.

For targeting only Retina Display

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="../iphone4.css" />
```

In your case the the second style sheet is loaded because in both cases (320 or 480px) your web view is under 640px.

i would recommend to use orientation as css media query for you case.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `head` of your HTML document:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>`

Comment: It tells the iPhone, "Act like you're 400px (or whatever) wide." The iPhone 'pretends' to have more pixels than it does to render websites not designed for small screens in their full size.

Answer (score 0):

Write `max-device-width` instead of `max-width`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width:960px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobileStyles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width:640px)" type="text/css" href="css/mobilePortraitStyles.css">
```

Also, it's better if you define their `orientation` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```